# How to ping a host with different MTU size to simulate icmpv6 packet too big scenario?

Tags: tcp, ipv6, wireshark, packet-capture, icmpv6

As the Title states,I want to check whether my host will actually send a ICMPv6 packet too big if i send a packet with beyond the defined MTU size.I don't have a cisco router(extended ping) to try out the scenario,Hence i would like to inject the message from a linux/windows based machine.

Please guide me to create this scenario or any wireshark pcap which have the request and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux it is `ping6 -s <packet_size> your.destination.com`.